# C: Problems Using Free() on Structs Elements, Strange Behivor

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having problems by freeing the elements on my struct.

*long code warning*

```
typedef struct bingo
{
    char board[5][5];
    int* luckNum;
    int* boardNum;
} bingo;

void update(bingo *pBingo,int num); //Function that gets a struct, number and checks if he is in the board, if it does he change it to "X"

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, j, m, k, temp[75], *parr;
    bingo player;

    //For rellocating them later
    if (!(player.luckNum = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int))))
    {
        printf("ERROR");
    }

    if (!(player.boardNum = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int))))
    {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    //giving temp values of 1-75
    for ( i = 0; i < 75; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = i + 1;
    }



    //Giving the player board random values of 1-75 without repeating the same number twice 
        for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) //Passing on the rows
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) //Passing on the columns
            {

            //
                do
                {
                    k = rand() % 75; //from 0-74 
                }
                while (temp[k] == NULL); //while temp[k] is marked 
                player.board[i][j] = temp[k];
                temp[k] = NULL; //NULL as a "flag" that marks the cell as taken (for not taking the same number twice)
                player.luckNum=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(i*j+j));
                player.luckNum[i*j + j] = player.board[i][j];
            }
        }

    //sets luckNum
        for ( i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", player.luckNum[i]);
        update(&player, player.luckNum[i]);
    }


    printf("\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",player.luckNum);
    }

    free(player.boardNum);
    free(player.luckNum);



    

    getchar();  
    return 0;
}

void update(bingo *pBingo, int num)
{
    int i, j, k;
    static int counter = 0,luckCounter = 25;



    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (num == (int) (pBingo->board[i][j]))
            {
                pBingo->board[i][j] = 'X';
                counter++;
                pBingo->boardNum = (int*) realloc(pBingo->boardNum, sizeof(int)*counter);
                pBingo->boardNum[counter] = num;

                for (k = 0; k < luckCounter; k++)
                {
                    if (pBingo->luckNum[k] == num)
                    {
                        num = pBingo->luckNum[k];
                        pBingo->luckNum[k] = pBingo->luckNum[luckCounter-1];
                        pBingo->luckNum[luckCounter-1] = num;
                        pBingo->luckNum = (int*) realloc(pBingo->luckNum, sizeof(int)*luckCounter);
                        luckCounter--;
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone recognize what interrupts the free() function from freeing the memory?. I'm new to C and working on this code about good days so sorry for my ignorance about free() function, can anyone help me?

Comment: One problem is that you allocate with malloc `player.luckNum` at the beginning of main and then in the nested loop (which seems completely wrong BTW).

Answer (score 0):

Ilan,

Don't be afraid to post your code with the necessary includes. First of all, are you heeding to the warnings of your compiler?

A few problem areas:

`while (temp[k] == NULL)`

You can research the difference between 0, NULL and '\0' but reserve the use of NULL for pointers. Also:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 25; i++)
   {
       printf("%d",player.luckNum);
   }
```

Printf is expecting an integer and you're giving it a pointer. Finally, to address what I think is your problem, when you write "..interrupts the free() function from freeing the memory?" Do you mean your program simply not returning? If so then get rid of the final getchar(). You're still going to have at least one leak in this program. This address of this malloc:

```
if (!(player.luckNum = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int))))
```

will be lost as you assigned luck.Num a new address here without freeing the first:

```
player.luckNum=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(i*j+j));
```